# Calculate confidence interval in Julia

Tags: statistics, julia

Basically, I have an array with a random sample from a population. I'm trying to calculate the 95% confidence interval for the true population mean.

I've looked into two libs, but they seemed to support just two-sample t-tests. (I'm not good at statistics so I'm probably missing something.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a [HypothesisTests.jl](https://github.com/simonster/HypothesisTests.jl) package that will do this for you.

```
using Distributions, HypothesisTests
data = rand(Normal(10,10),100)
ci(OneSampleTTest(data))
```

Comment: I think `ci` has been deprecated in favor of `confint`.

Answer (score 5):

Likely this is wrapped up in a function somewhere, but here is a direct way to do so assuming a normal population:

```
using Distributions
function t_test(x; conf_level=0.95)
    alpha = (1 - conf_level)
    tstar = quantile(TDist(length(x)-1), 1 - alpha/2)
    SE = std(x)/sqrt(length(x))

    lo, hi = mean(x) + [-1, 1] * tstar * SE
    "($lo, $hi)"
end
```

Comment: For now I think this is the only way to do this.

Comment: It would be nice to be able to define an infix ± operator like cell 56 of http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/StefanKarpinski/b8fe9dbb36c1427b9f22 but I think that notebook is done on a private branch of `julia`.